# Regex to allow periods unless it's alone

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to create a name verification regex that allows users to use names like `St. Germain` but I don't want names that are only a period like `.` which it currently accepts.

my current regex is `/^[A-Za-z\ -\.\']+$/`

Comment: `^(?!\.+$)[a-zA-Z .'-]+$` Btw, `\ -.` will match any character in that range, not those characters specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from @Mong Zhu's example but allowing first word without dots as well:

```
\w+\.?\s?\w+
```

Answer (score 0):

### Brief

Your current regex has a potential unwanted bug `\ -.`, which will match any character in the range from space to dot. I'm not sure if this is the intended behaviour, if so, you can use the second regex below.

---

### Code

**Version 1**

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/rmzyK4/1)

```
^(?!\.+$)[a-zA-Z .'-]+$
```

**Version 2**

```
^(?!\.+$)[a-zA-Z -.']+$
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
username
.
Something.a
...
.Some
some. some
some.
```

#### Output

**Note:** Only matches are shown below

```
username
Something.a
.Some
some. some
some.
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?!\.+$)` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows is not the dot character `\.` literally, one or more times, asserting the ending position at the end of the line
- `[a-zA-Z .'-]+` Any character in the set `a-zA-Z .'-` between one and unlimited times
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

---

### Additionally

You may want to use `p{L}` instead of `a-zA-Z` to accept foreign characters